# jquery ajax success not called in ie8,9

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery

The below code is working fine in other browsers but not in IE7+.
I already went through the other solution related to this type of issue but didnt work for me.

I already added alert to test it in IE but it didnt called.
While in IE9 in "Network" section of developer console I saw the response with valid data.Still the ajax success function is not called.
Don't know the exact cause.

If anybody have any pointer / idea on this would really help me .

Thanks in Advance !!!!!

```
function callExternalWSUsingAjax(request,response){


 if ('XDomainRequest' in window && window.XDomainRequest !== null) {
   // override default jQuery transport
  $.ajaxSettings.xhr = function() {
      try { return new XDomainRequest(); }
      catch(e) { }
  };
   // also, override the support check
  $.support.cors = true;
 }
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: "false"
  });
  $.ajax({
            async : false,
            url: "https://externaldomain.com/services/myrestservicw/SearchCountry",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    name_startsWith: request.term
            },
            success: function(resp, txtS, xhr) {
            if (xhr.status==200) {      

                alert(xhr.status);   // not called in IE
            } else {
                alert('EEE'+xhr.status);
           }
        },
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest,status,error){
            alert('E : '+error + 'Status : ' + status) ;
        }
});

}
```

Comment: I face a similar issue, did you fix yours?